# How to merge additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json with kapt when using Kotlin and Gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I have read these documents but I don’t know how to merge `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` with `kapt` when using Kotlin and Gradle.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/appendix-configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kotlin-configuration-properties

I managed to merge it this way, but I want to know the official way.

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.3.61"
}

dependencies {
    kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    …
}

kapt {
    arguments {
        arg(
            "org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.additionalMetadataLocations",
            "$projectDir/src/main/resources"
        )
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks about pointing out the configuration `org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.additionalMetadataLocations`.
I've read the source codes of spring-boot-configuration-processor, the key locations is `org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.MetadataStore#locateAdditionalMetadataFile`.
The default behavior find additional json file in the **class output** path.
But in gradle build, additional json file is located in `$buildDir/resources/main`.

Comment: That looks like a bug in kapt to me.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an answer here for better visibility. This is a known issue in the Kapt maven plugin that does not make sure the compilation classpath is available when the annotation processor runs. The implementation can't see the file and therefore won't merge it.

Your workaround works and there is an issue [you can vote for](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41217) in the JetBrains issue tracker.